# Python 2.5 - multi-threaded for loop

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop

I've got a piece of code:

```
for url in get_lines(file):
    visit(url, timeout=timeout)
```

It gets URLs from file and visit it (by *urllib2*) in for loop.

Is is possible to do this in few threads? For example, 10 visits at the same time.

---

I've tried:

```
for url in get_lines(file):
    Thread(target=visit, args=(url,), kwargs={"timeout": timeout}).start()
```

But it does not work - no effect, URLs are visited normally.

---

The simplified version of function *visit*:

```
def visit(url, proxy_addr=None, timeout=30):
    (...)
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    return response.read()
```

Comment: `Thread(...).start` should spawn a new thread to run `visit`. How do you know that the access is sequential?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on senderle's answer, you can use the Pool class in multiprocessing to do this easily:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=5)
pages = pool.map(visit, get_lines(file))
```

When the map function returns then "pages" will be a list of the contents of the URLs.  You can adjust the number of processes to whatever is suitable for your system.

Comment: I just realized that you specified python 2.5 in the question, and multiprocessing was new in 2.6.  If you can't upgrade this may not be that useful to you.  Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you've run into the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock). Basically, [`threading`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#module-threading) in python can't achieve concurrency, which seems to be your goal. You need to use [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) instead.

`multiprocessing` is designed to have a roughly analogous interface to `threading`, but it has a few quirks. Your `visit` function as written above *should* work correctly, I believe, because it's written in a functional style, without side effects.

In `multiprocessing`, the `Process` class is the equivalent of the `Thread` class in `threading`. It has all the same methods, so it's a drop-in replacement in this case. (Though I suppose you could use `pool` as [JoeZuntz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9926372/577088) suggests -- but I would test with the basic `Process` class first, to see if it fixes the problem.)

Comment: Hmm, what about the fact that GIL is released during I/O?: http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock

Comment: @ArjunShankar, I thought of that, but I'm not sure that applies in this case. Possibly it could be made to work acceptably if the threads were pure I/O threads, but the move to `multiprocessing` should work too, and is more extensible.

Comment: Agreed. I was just surprised by the OPs comment that threading had "no effect, URLs are visited normally". So now waiting for OPs follow-up.