# C# Parallel.Foreach equivalent in Python

Tags: c#, python, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have 96 txt files that have to be processed. Right now I am using a for loop and doing them one at a time, this process is very slow. The resulting 96 files, do not need to be merged. Is there a way to make them run in parallel, ala Parallel.foreach in C#?
Current code:

```
for src_name in glob.glob(source_dir+'/*.txt'):
   outfile = open (...)
   with open(...) as infile:
      for line in infile:
         --PROCESS--
   for --condition--:
      outfile.write(...)
   infile.close()
   outfile.close()
```

Want this process to run in parallel for all files in source_dir.

Comment: Is the process taking long or is this the reading?

Comment: In the case of CPython, which has a GIL (global interpreter lock), you would need to use the `multiprocessing` module. But you are in luck because there have been many third-party libraries made on top of multiprocessing for parallel computing.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @Thomas: The total processing time of the 96 files is very slow. I am trying to improve the processing time for one single file, but would be nice to have parallel threads as simply as how its done in C#

Comment: @Reise45 is it *always* the same 96 files? how long (in lines) is the processing ?

Comment: @Thomas: No. different set of files everytime. Files are quite huge, about a million lines each. I can't seem to find a simple syntax to run in parallel, also not sure how to select number of threads to assign.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925749/python-2-5-multi-threaded-for-loop/9926372#9926372

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that the limiting factor is indeed the processing and not the I/O, you can use [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/index.html) to easily run your loop on multiple CPUs.

A [simple example from their documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html):

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> from joblib import Parallel, delayed
>>> Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in range(10))
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```